# What missions unlock all the skills?

Tags: far-cry-3

I've hit a point where I have 6 skill points but all of the skills are still locked.

At what point do the skills start unlocking and is there a point at which all of them unlock at once?

Comment: There are only two such mission, but I don t remember their name. One of them is when you access the second island, the other is when you kill one of the bosses (no spoiler tag for comment). Need to confirm thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You unlock the first batch of locked skill when you meet Citra for the first time:

For the lasts skills, you need to meet with Citra again, before Payback where you

> go kill Vaas

Answer (score -1):

As you progress through the game, the skills should start to unlock as you get farther. I had the same situation where I had skill points but the skills were still locked, so I got farther into the game and they eventually unlocked.

Comment: Actually, ChaseC ask what is the mission unlocking the lasts skills...